Groovy POST request with form filling in it
I need to write a script similar to this cURL
curl -X 'POST' 'url/authenticate' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F 'Username=user_name' -F 'Password=pass_word'

I have this, but Request Response Code 400 says that Password field is required and Username field is required
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import groovyx.net.http.Method

def http = new HTTPBuilder('url/authenticate')

def body = [
    "Username": 'user_name',
    "Password": 'pass_word'
]

http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.URLENC) {
    headers.'Accept' = '*/*'
    body = body
    response.success = { resp, reader ->
        log.warn("Response Status: ${resp.statusLine}")
        log.warn("Response Data: ${reader}")
    }
    response.failure = { resp, reader ->
        log.warn("Error Response Status: ${resp.statusLine}")
        log.warn("Error Response Data: ${reader}")
    }
}

How correctly pass form fields in this script?
P.S. POST request works fine from Postman, that provide this form fields in request body

public static String getAuthToken(){
        def http = new HTTPBuilder(url + "some/url")   
        http.request (POST) { multipartRequest ->
            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartRequestEntity = new MultipartEntityBuilder()
            String key = 
            multipartRequestEntity.addPart('Username', new StringBody(user))
            multipartRequestEntity.addPart('Password', new StringBody(password))

            multipartRequest.entity = multipartRequestEntity.build()

            response.success = { resp, data ->
                return data['token']
            }
            response.failure = { resp, data ->
                return data
            }
        }
    }

U can perform form filling by using MultipartRequestEntityBuilder

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can use a PAT (Personal Access Token) instead of basic authentication:
def oauthToken = 'Your Token'
try {
    def connection = new URL(url).openConnection()
    connection.requestMethod = 'GET'
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + oauthToken)
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
    connection.connect()
    ...
    ...


I needed to make a request with form filling to get this token)
